# Generate unique image name and save to target folder

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have this form where you can upload an image that will serve as your profile picture. The image's name gets register to the database, so it would be wise to use a unique name that will serve as the image's name before registering it to the database to avoid future errors and stuffs.

Here's the code that I come up:

```
function random_str($type = 'alphanum', $length = 8)
{
  switch($type)
  {
      case 'basic'    : return mt_rand();
          break;
      case 'alpha'    :
      case 'alphanum' :
      case 'num'      :
      case 'nozero'   :
              $seedings             = array();
              $seedings['alpha']    = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
              $seedings['alphanum'] = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
              $seedings['num']      = '0123456789';
              $seedings['nozero']   = '123456789';

              $pool = $seedings[$type];

              $str = '';
              for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++)
              {
                  $str .= substr($pool, mt_rand(0, strlen($pool) -1), 1);
              }
              return $str;
          break;
      case 'unique'   :
      case 'md5'      :
                  return md5(uniqid(mt_rand()));
          break;
  }
}

$key = random_str('alphanum', 12);


if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    $target = "profiles/".$key.basename($_FILES['image']['name']); 

    $image = $key.basename($_FILES['image']['name']);


    $sql = "UPDATE users SET img = '$image' WHERE idnumber = $idnumber";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        header("Location:home.php");
    } else {
        header("Location:error_uploading.php");
    }
}
```

The only problem is that, for example the image's original filename is `image1.png`, it generates the name `sK1ls902nzAlimage1.png`. I know this is kinda overkill but how can I get rid of that `...image1.png` in the end? And is my code any good? Or is there a better way (shorter way) to do it? Thanks!

Comment: uniqid would be simpler. your code is overkill

Comment: Why the "html" and "jquery" tags? If you're storing images in a database, why wouldn't you define the table in question to have an auto-incremented key field as a unique identifier rather than using the file name?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are wanting to remove `image1` from `sK1ls902nzAlimage1.png` *(it doesn't make sense to remove the ext)*:

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    # Get extension
    $ext     = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    # Create image file name
    $image   = "{$key}.{$ext}";
    # Create image path final destination
    $target  = "profiles/{$image}";
    # Check if the upload is successful
    $success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target);
    # If successful, set home page, save to database
    if($success) {
        $path = "home";
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET img = '{$image}' WHERE idnumber = {$idnumber}");
    }
    else
        $path = "error_uploading";

    header("Location: {$path}.php");
    exit;
}
```

This will just save:

```
sK1ls902nzAl.png
```

If you really only want to remove the extension as well, this line needs to just be:

```
# Will be sK1ls902nzAl vs sK1ls902nzAl.png
$image   = $key;
```